# How do I find the variance of $\overline{X}^2 - \frac{1}{n}$ where $X_i\sim N(\theta,1)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, variance

I have a problem here. The question asks to compare the UMVUE and MVBE of $\theta^2$ considering a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ from a $N(\theta,1)$ distribution.

I found out the Cramer Rao Lower Bound for the variance of an unbiased estimator for estimating $\theta^2$ to be $\frac{4\theta^2}{n}$. Since $\overline{X}$ came out to be a sufficient and complete statistic, I used this to get the UMVUE which is  $T = \overline{X}^2 - \frac{1}{n}$. 
Now I have to find the variance of $T$.

Now,$Var[T]=Var[\overline{X}^2]$.
I see that $Z=n(\overline{X} - \theta)^2$ has a $\chi_1^2$ distribution. So,
 $Var[Z] = 2$
$\implies Var[(\overline{X} - \theta)^2]= \frac{2}{n^2}$
$\implies Var[\overline{X}^2 +\theta^2 - 2\overline{X}\theta] = \frac{2}{n^2}$
$\implies Var[\overline{X}^2] + Var[2\overline{X}\theta] = \frac{2}{n^2}$
$\implies Var[\overline{X}^2] = \frac{2}{n^2} - Var[2\overline{X}\theta]$
$\implies Var[\overline{X}^2] = \frac{2}{n^2} - \frac{4\theta^2}{n}=Var[T]$

The answer says that $Var[T] = \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{4\theta^2}{n}$. 
So where am I going wrong?

Edit: My teacher had used this method which I wasn’t able to understand in two places. If someone could clarify this for me,would be great.

$Var[T] = Var[\overline{X}^2] = E[\overline{X}^4] - E^2[\overline{X}^2]$
$=E[\overline{X}^4] - (\mu^2 +\frac{1}{n})^2$
Now, $E[\overline{X}^4]=E[\overline{X} - \mu + \mu]^4$
$=E[\overline{X} - \mu]^4 + 4E[\overline{X}-\mu]^3\mu + 6E[\overline{X}-\mu]^2\mu^2 +4E[\overline{X}-\mu]\mu^3 +\mu^4$
$=3\frac{1}{n^2} + 0 + 6\frac{1}{n}\mu^2 + 0 + \mu^4$.

I can’t understand how the first two terms came about in the last step.

Comment: Please explain though. Since I thought V(X+Y-Z) = V(X) + V(Y) + V(Z), where X,Y and Z are all independent distributed random variables.

Comment: You go for $\mathsf{Var}(\overline{X}^2-2\overline{X}\theta)=\mathsf{Var}(\overline{X}^2)+\mathsf{Var}(2\overline{X}\theta)$, but $\overline{X}^2$ and $2\overline{X}\theta$ are not independent.

Comment: Oh,damn. Okay,I see it now. Could you suggest a way to find the variance of T?

Comment: You could try out $\mathsf{Var}(X+Y)=\mathsf{Covar}(X+Y,X+Y)=\mathsf{Var}(X)+2\mathsf{Covar}(X,Y)+\mathsf{Var}(Y)$ (applying bilinearity of covariance). This for rv's $\overline{X}^2$ and $2\overline{X}\theta$. I do not exclude that it can be simpler because I only had a short look on your question.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to add some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are iid normal rvs with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$ then: $$Z:=\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\mu\right)$$
has standard normal distribution so that $\mathbb{E}Z^{4}=3$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)).

That leads to $\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{4}\right)=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n^{2}}Z^{4}=\frac{3}{n^{2}}$
and $\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\overline{X}-\mu\right)^{3}\right)=\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}Z^{3}=0$